# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout - What is missing in the main?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

*Before put -1 in the score, I tell you that I read all, I repeat ALL the answers about this problem in this site and even in other site, so, if you can give me an hand.*

Hi guys, i'm having this problem with my application and I'm wasting too much time in this.

My application is composed by 4 fragments, and I'm having problems with the two with the recyclerview (in fragment_fibra and fragment_adsl).

**main.java**

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity implements 
OnFragmentInteractionListener //I HAVE a problem with 
OnFragmentInteractionListener {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    // tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager); //aggiunta dopo
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_homepage, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fibra, container, false);
                break;
            case 3:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adsl, container, false);
                break;
            case 4:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aiuto, container, false);
                break;
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1);
            case 1:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(2);
            case 2:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(3);
            case 3:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(4);
            default: return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1);
// here i have other problems, so like this the app still work, but if i change something it crash (and I know it's wrong like this)
        }
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
}
```

**activity_homepage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".homepage">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_4" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**homepage.java** (first fragment)

```
public class homepage extends AppCompatActivity {
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_homepage, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;

        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fibra, container, false);
                break;
            case 3:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adsl, container, false);
                break;
            case 4:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aiuto, container, false);
                break;
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
}
```

**fragment_fibra.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fibra"
android:background="#EFEFEF">

<Button
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  android:drawablePadding="22dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:hint="@string/cercasugg"
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:padding="16dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/ListaFibra"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fibra.java** (second fragment)

```
public class fibra extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

public fibra() {
        }
public static fibra newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    fibra fragment = new fibra();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fibra, container, false);
    recyclerView = V.findViewById(R.id.ListaFibra);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        input.add("Test" + i);
    }
    mAdapter = new adFibra(input);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return V;

    /*View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fibra, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListaFibra);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); //per migliorare performance

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    adFibra adapter = new adFibra(new String[]{"Example One"});
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;*/
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fibra, container, false);
}
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

before

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

so it will be

```
   LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

 MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"Example One", "Example Two", "Example Three", "Example Four", "Example Five" , "Example Six" , "Example Seven"});
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Happy Coding :D

Comment: Nothing, same problem :(

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you actually call the fibra fragment?

You are creating a PlaceHolderFragment every time and just inflating different layouts. You don't actually create a fibra fragment, so the recycler is not populated, thus the message.

In your SectionsPagerAdapter, in method getItem, return the fragment instance that corresponds to the position.

For example:

```
switch (position) {
   case 0:
      return homepage.newInstance();                
   case 1:
      return fibra.newInstance();
   case 2:
      return adsl.newInstance();
   case 3:
      return aiuto.newInstance();
   default:
      return homepage.newInstance();      
}
```

Remove the PlaceHolderFragment from your main activity. Also homepage is not a fragment, but an activity. All your fragments should look like fibra.

And implement all the fragment interfaces like:

```
implements fibra.OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

and create a method to implement it:

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
     // your code here...   
}
```

Comment: What i need to change? I mean, return...? Excuse me, I'm not so good xD

Comment: Don't worry, is not me

Comment: It tells me "missing return statement after the } of the method

Comment: yes since the default clause doesn't return something. Add your default fragment, I gues that's the first so : default: return firstFragment.newInstance("param1","param2");

Comment: Nothing, it's crashing Process: com.egb.adsltool, PID: 2504
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.egb.adsltool.main@35ecf9f must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: This is because your homebase activity must implement the fragment's interface. Add: homepage extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener.

Comment: Wait, i changed something cause i find a big problem. First of all, I made another java class, the real main; second the homepage is just a fragment, the first fragment, and i was using it as a main. I've updated the code.

Comment: Always a problem even with implements fibra.OnFragmentInteractionListener, i give up, thanks for everything